# Use Wildfly as reverse proxy authorisation gateway with Keycloak Authorisation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, reverse-proxy, keycloak

TL;DR: We have authorization mechanism implemented in Wildfly (= Keycloak adapter). How can we redirect all HTTP requests which pass through authorization to a remote server? (Make Wildfly into reverse proxy + authorisation gateway)

Keycloak works well with Wildfly and provides authentication and authorization capabilities suitable for us. At the same time, we already have services running on another server which we do not want to develop from scratch.

I would like to use Wildfly+Keycloak just as a gatekeeper and redirect authorized requests to the current server and refuse unauthorized requests.

Keycloak has many examples how to enforce security policies using the Wildfly adapter. It is fairly easy, they just ad KEYCLOAK to web.xml and use keycloak.json config file e.g. :  https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/authz/servlet-authz/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.

I would like to further modify the web.xml in order to proxy all authorized HTTP requests to our current server. It can be also done in .java file. I am not sure which would be the easiest option.